# comment count statistic

Tags: views, 6, comments

Hi I'm Drupal beginner.

I'm trying to make a view which shows most commented content today, this week, this month, total in Drupal 6.

I only found the total comment count field.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the total comments is the right field.  You'll have to make different views to show all content from today, this week, this month....THEN sort the view by most comments (so that the highest is first), then restrict your view to show 1 item, and VOILA! (should work)

Comment: To restrict the content to a time range, you'll use a filter based on the node's post date. You'll need to make a new display in the view for each different filter variation.